# Show that group of order $20449$ is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I am trying to solve a problem of the following type:

> Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$. Show that it is solvable. (Note that the problems are stated such that for this particular $n$ they are solvable).

In particular, let $G$ be of order $20449 = 11^2 13^2$. Now, using Sylow's Third Theorem, by letting $n_{13}$ be the number of Sylow $13$-subgroups in $G$, we have the following constraints

$$n_{13} \equiv 1 \pmod{13} \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad n_{13} \mid 11^2 13^2.$$

How does it follow from these constraints that $n_{13} = 1$?

And in general, how do I know which prime factor to choose i.e. in this case $n_{11}$ or $n_{13}$ in order to get $n_{11} = 1$ or $n_{13} = 1$?

Comment: Well, that is false. If it happens to be that $\;n=60\;$ and $\;G=A_5\;$ then the group is not only **not** solvable, but it is in fact *a simple* group...Now, for **certain** values of $\;n\;$ that is true.

Comment: Note that the problems are stated such that for this particular $n$ they are solvable.

Comment: @Jarden Yes... **now the problem** is stated correctly, after you added those parentheses...

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that. I, in my mind, considered only the ones that are actually solvable. Should've communicated the problem with all constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be that $\;n_{13}=1\pmod{13}\;$ **and** $\;n_{13}\,\mid\,11^2\;$  . But neither $\;11\;$ nor $\;11^2=121\;$ are of the form $\;13k+1\;$ , for some $\;k\in\Bbb N\implies\;$ it must be $\;n_{13}=1\;$ ... Fill in details.

Comment: Hey,  you need to type faster! ;)

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about! :)

Comment: @DonAntonio And for instance when I am faced with the choice of applying Sylow's Third Theorem to say prime factors $n_{1}, n_{2}$ or $n_{3}$. How do I know which one to pick such that we will eventually get $n_{i} = 1$? Just trial and error?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Nothing at all...:) :)

Comment: @jardon You take, of course, the primes that divide the group's order since that's what Sylow's theorems say...Now, if there are several primes dividing that order then it can be a little messier to do that, and in some cases it won't be possible to reach the desired result that way. You'll need then more advances results...

Comment: @jardon The fact is that you don't know - try out all of them! Either it will work (one of $Syl_{n_i}(G)$ will end up being $1$) or it won't work (i.e. there will be a *possibility* that all $Syl_{n_i}(G)$ are $>1$).

Comment: (Cont'd) In the second case, sometimes just by counting elements in the group you can prove that this case is actually impossible. Or, sometimes you will be able to use some other theorem (such that a subgroup of index $2$ is always normal, or that if you can find a subgroup of very small index $k$ then index of its "normal core" divides $k!$ and this may be small enough number to conclude the latter is nontrivial etc.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop I see. Thanks! The reason why I was asking is because I thought there might be some technique to spot the one that will work. Since during exams you have a timer and you can't try out everything.

Comment: @jardon In my experience, this is a routine part of the problem. If $n=p^kq$ where $p$-prime, $p\not\mid q$, then $Syl_p(G)\equiv 1\pmod p$ and $Syl_p(G)\mid q$, you factorize $q$ and see which factors are $\equiv 1\pmod p$. This can be done in a minute. Bigger problems happen when your problem is such that you cannot claim any of $Syl_p(G)$ are $1$ - so make sure you practice enough this routine part so that it becomes a real routine for you, and then concentrate on the hard part.

Answer (score 2):

You know that $n_{13}$ divides $11^2$. This means it is $1,11$ or $121$. Do any of $11$ or $121$ leave remainder $1$ when divided by $13$? No. Hence, the only option is that $n_{13}=1$.